# How to send user data to react js after logging in when passport google oauth 20?

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, google-oauth

Hi I got 2 servers running

backend server is running on port 3000 & react is running on port 3001

I have already setup the server route for the login
Its look like this

```
router.get("/google",passport.authenticate("google", {
scope: ["profile"],
}))

router.get("/",(req,res) => {
  res.send("Hello")
})


router.get("/google/callback",
passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: ["/nouser"]),
 function(req,res) {
   console.log(req.user);
   res.redirect("/")
   }
  })
```

When i console.log req.user Its returning user data which is an object.
So How can i access the user data from the app.js Which is a react file (frontend)

Comment: you can put `res.send(JSON.stringify(req.user))` just before your redirect ?

Comment: Should I replay the res.redirect with the res.send @SethLutske

Comment: I mean it depends what you want to do.  I'm not sure why you'd redirect on authentication, but I also don't know what you're trying to build.  But using a `res.send` will send your `req.user` back to your front end, or wherever you're calling this route from